"kp" internet slang
I came across a post in an internet discussion forum which included the phrase

ach kp ...

Google translate renders this as "Oh I don't know." Apparently "kp" is an abbreviation for "keinen Plan," and in this context "Plan" is taken to mean "idea" or "clue". (This is meaning 5 in the Wiktionary entry.)
What I don't get is how does "Plan", which I thought meant, well, "plan", come to mean "idea" or "clue". I'm used to "keine Ahnung" meaning "no idea" or "I don't know," so does "keinen Plan" have the same meaning?

Be aware that, also in "internet slang", "kp" might also be used for "kein Problem" = "no problem", which can be the direct opposite of "keinen Plan".

The german noun »der Plan« does not only mean »plan«, »map«, »scedule«, »scheme« or »diagram« but also »idea«, »concept« and »proposition«, i.e. a picture that you have in mind of something complex that already exists in real life or might become reality soon.
Sadly you didn't mention the context of the conversation, so I have to guess. I guess that it was in a chat group in internet and the topic could be the conflict of special relativity with quantum physics or the influence that the upcoming US administration will have on the prices of Dutch tulip bulbs or the recipe for Mrs. Schwarzenegger's apple strudel. In any case, it was a complicated topic in which not all participants had the know-how to fully participate in the discussion. And in such a situation one participant might say: »Pooh, I really have no idea.« And the German translation of this sentence is:

Pfuh, ich hab' echt keinen Plan.
Pooh, I really have no idea.

The short version is

kein Plan
no idea

or (when not spoken, but written) just »kP« or more often even »kp« when someone is too lazy to press the shift key.

The German noun »die Ahnung« is derived from the verb »ahnen« which means »to suspect, to sense, to guess, to forebode, to presage, to divine etc.« And therefore »die Ahnung« means »intuition, anticipation, presentiment, inkling, suspicion« but of course also »idea«.
So, the fields of meaning or German »der Plan« and »die Ahnung« overlap, and they overlap with the English noun »the idea« but they are not identical. Also the fields of meaning of the negations »kein Plan«, »keine Ahnung« and »no idea« overlap, and these negations overlap even more, but still there is a subtile difference in the meaning.
Note, that German, like English imported the greek word ἰδέα (idéa) into their vocabularies many centuries ago. It's »the idea« in English and »die Idee« in German. The original meaning of this word was »a thought«. But while the English noun »the idea« has a relatively broad meaning, that includes most aspects of German »Plan« and »Ahnung«, the German noun »die Idee« has more the meaning of »sudden inspiration«. So, the negation of German »Idee« (»keine Idee«) does not mean, that you have no idea but it means, that you have no inspiration.

Sorry about not including the context; it was about how difficult the battle system is in a particularly challenging video game. I thought the expression was common enough that a specific context didn't matter. The link, if you're really interested, is https://steamcommunity.com/app/379430/discussions/0/591758483838291692/

Yes, it does have the same meaning.
Think of 'kein(en) Plan' to be short for 'Ich habe keinen Plan wie ich die Frage beantworten könnte' in the sense of missing means or a solving strategy for the question or problem. Practically it is really synonymous and not just used for complex hard-to-get answers where you first need to come up with a plan on how to find a solution (which you don't have).

As others have already explained, it is synonymous with "keine Ahnung".
In my opinion "kein Plan" and especially the abbreviation kp is often used when shrugging off a question and/or indicating that you're not really interested in pursuing the topic further, while not being offensive.
It's a simple one-liner (or 2 letter) to let others know you're completely clueless about it and likely don't care too much.

I would compare it to "no concept" in English:

He had no concept of how any of this worked.

I think the main reason why "keinen Plan" has kind of replaced "keine Ahnung" with a younger generation is just that it is more fun to say. "Keine Ahnung" or even "nicht die leiseste Ahnung" are idiomatic of an older generation than "keinen Plan".

I've heard a similar explanation for "auf den Keks gehen"; basically substitute "Keks" for one of the original possible words, just to be different. The youth -- such scamps.
